# How to merge file when unarchive the tarball?

Tags: mac, vim, macbook, plugins, tar

I downloaded a tarball(`abc.tar.gz`) which has a root folder(`abc`) and multiple subfolders(`a`, `b`, `c`, etc). And I have a folder called `Target` in machine(macbook pro), with multiple subfolders(`a`, `b`, `c`, etc) either.
**Now I want to unarchive the tarball to `Target` folder and auto merge the subfolders. How can I achieve it?** I've tried to unarchive it in `Target` but result with a subfolder(`abc`) in `Target`:

```
cp abc.tar.gz ~/Target
cd ~/Target
tar xzvf abc.tar.gz
```

Result:

```
Target/abc/a
Target/abc/b
Target/a
Target/b
```

What I want is:

```
Target/a    # auto merged
Target/b    # auto merged
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `tar` will always unpack the full archived path even when you only request a single resource inside a subfolder path. e.g.:

```
$ tar -x abc/a -zvf abc.tar.gz
```

will unpack only subfolder **a** but it's parent directory **abc** will still be created.

From the Target directory you can do

```
$ for d in `ls abc`; do cp -rf abc/$d/* ./$d/; done
```

to copy the archive folders into pre-existing, same-name folders in the current folder `Target`

or simply

```
$ cp -rf abc/* ./
```

to create all archive folders in `~/Target`. If a folder named, say,  'foo' exists in both `abc` and `Target` then the contents of `abc/foo` will be copied to `Target/foo`. Be aware, however, that at the file level `abc/foo/bar.txt` will overwrite `Target/foo/bar.txt` without notice or warning.

Comment: `mv ./abc/a ./a` will not work in mac, it just move the folder `./abc/a` into `./a` as a subfolder. Instead I use `cp -rf abc/a/* ./a/`(or just `cp -rf abc/* ./`). but I feel it is little bit cumbersome.. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion. :D

Comment: i updated my answer to reflect this as a one-line loop. BTW which shell are you using? perhaps `mv ./abc/a ./` (destination is simply the current directory) should work?

Comment: Thanks @verzen, my shell is `bash`. And I tried `mv ./abc/a ./` with error:`mv: rename ./abc/a to ./a: Directory not empty`. `cp -rf abc/* ./` works well. Maybe you can add this cl to your answer and I'll accept it if there's no better answer. :p

Comment: answer updated. This behavior of bash in MacOSX is interesting... I see in [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-in-a-directory-to-another) that a `shopt -s dotglob nullglob` might be needed for bash in OSX to behave as expected...